# Exception in while loop while counting the time [Ardiuno|LED-matrix]

Tags: c, time, while-loop, arduino, counting

I'm a programming noob and have worked on one project for ages ...
It's gonna be a word clock. A matrix of 160 LEDs (WS2812B) in combination with an ardiuno uno were used to display a certain time.

After searching for similar projects I found [this one from dgoersch](https://github.com/dgoersch/wordclock). I don't use the eeprom library and "just want to hard-code" the time and the events (switch on and off of LED arrays).

I used the delay function to wait for each minute to change LEDs. But if I want to use a button-push interrupt to change the hours and minutes manually (next implementation on the list) it won't work because the arduino can't react while it is in the delay. Therefore I found the while loop and a method to count the time and change the index if a certain time-interval has passed.
Pls find the code snippet for the counting hours below:

```
void loop()
{
  //the current time for every loop-run
  unsigned long currentHourMillis = millis(); 
  // checking time-difference if time-interval has passed or not
  while ((unsigned long)(currentHourMillis - previousHourMillis) >= intervalHour) 
  {
    // if the time-interval was passed, a new previous time will be saved
    previousHourMillis = millis(); 
    if (i < 1)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhZwoelf, sizeof(wordhZwoelf) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhEin, sizeof(wordhEin) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 2)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhEin, sizeof(wordhEin) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhZwei, sizeof(wordhZwei) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 3)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhZwei, sizeof(wordhZwei) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhDrei, sizeof(wordhDrei) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 4)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhDrei, sizeof(wordhDrei) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhVier, sizeof(wordhVier) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 5)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhVier, sizeof(wordhVier) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhFuenf, sizeof(wordhFuenf) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 6)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhFuenf, sizeof(wordhFuenf) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhSechs, sizeof(wordhSechs) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 7)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhSechs, sizeof(wordhSechs) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhSieben, sizeof(wordhSieben) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 8)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhSieben, sizeof(wordhSieben) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhAcht, sizeof(wordhAcht) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 9)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhAcht, sizeof(wordhAcht) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhNeun, sizeof(wordhNeun) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 10)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhNeun, sizeof(wordhNeun) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhZehn, sizeof(wordhZehn) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 11)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhZehn, sizeof(wordhZehn) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhElf, sizeof(wordhElf) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 12)
    {
      word2stripe(wordhElf, sizeof(wordhElf) / sizeof(int), CRGB::Black);
      word2stripe(wordhZwoelf, sizeof(wordhZwoelf) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));
      FastLED.show(); Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    else if (i < 13)
    {
      i = 0; Serial.println("Stunde"); Serial.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

I declared:

```
int i = 0; 
unsigned long intervalHour = 10000;// the time we need to wait for an hour
unsigned long previousHourMillis = 0;// millis() returns an unsigned long
```

before the setup() starts.

My problem:

I want to count the hours in a AM - PM style. (from 12 to 11 and then loop through) The while condition needs to be true to show the first LEDs. But I need an array of LEDs (hour 12 : `word2stripe(wordhZwoelf, sizeof(wordhZwoelf) / sizeof(int), CRGB( 8, 75, 10));`) while the time is counting till the first `intervalHour` because there is not such thing as hour zero.

Is there any possibility to code an exception in the while loop while it's counting to the first time-interval?

Comment: Why not initialize `i` to 1, and reset it to 1?  As for an *exception*, that term is used for something else. What you could do is detect the unwanted state and use the `continue;` statement, which tells the `while` loop that you don't want to do anything more in this iteration and to start the next pass through the loop. I don't know if it will actually help you in this situation (I didn't study your code enough).

Comment: You should look at the Time library.  It might help you a LOT.  It's hard to code around AM-PM stuff.  Normally we write the code in terms of minutes since midnight or seconds since midnight or something like that and only convert to human readable time when we want to display something for a human.  That makes coding a lot easier.

Comment: Hi and thx for the answers.

The "simple" and hopefully tenacious solution is to switch on the LEDs first in the `setup()`body of the `.io` code. 

So the arduino will initiate this line before looping and ignore it afterwards.

@aMike: I had a similar idea with the index, but the unwanted "delay" of the while loop does not bypass the "waiting for the time-interval" itself.
@Delta_G: for a smarte version I think I need to have a look at the time or eeprom library